# Performance of system("rm x.*") vs unlink()?

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems

I'm maintaining a Linux legacy system which maintains millions of small files in a large storage array.  (yes, filesystem nightmare)

In the C++ code I found files being deleted like system("rm -f /dir/dir/file.*")

I suspect using unlink() is going to be a lot faster, but **how much faster?**  (I can't really test it in production)

Anybody have some comparative data on this?

The old code is already fragile and replacing the handy system() calls with unlink() and getting the globbing to work, etc, is a good chunk of work...

Answer (score 2):

Without actually setting this up and testing it (on the type of machine, with the correct infrastructure in place - e.g. network files behave different from hard disk files, which again are different from flash-drive or SSD files), it's really not possible to answer precisely. However, we can discuss "what is the overhead of one over the the other":

`unlink()` is a function call in your own executable, which then translates to the relevant system call in the kernel. Your code will have to iterate over the relevant files to be deleted.

`system("rm something")` will translate to `fork(); exec("sh", "rm", "something");`, and the shell will perform `glob()` on the `"something"`, which expands to the relevant list of files, and then execute `rm`, which quite quickly turns into `unlink()`, but there is a little bit of overhead.

Ultimately, it really comes down to the number of files and potentially what filesystem they are stored in. If there are LOTS of files (hundreds or thousands), then then overhead of calling `system` is miniscule. On the other hand, if you do something like `for_each(list_of_files) system("rm " + file_in_list);` [that's not MEANT to compile], the overhead over `for_each(list_of_files) unlink(file_in_list);` will be noticeable for a large number of files.

Generally, deleting large numbers of files becomes I/O bound quite quickly, so whatever method you use, will depend on "how quickly the filesystem can deal with the request to delete the file", rather than the speed of the code actually asking for it to be deleted.

It would be extremely surprising if you can measure any difference between these two solutions for more than a few dozen files - since the time is so dominated by the time it takes to actually perform the filesystem operation (reading the directory, removing the file from the directory list, storing the directory list back). Tuning the filesystem parameters is much more likely (if not already tuned) to give you some benefit (for example, reduce the criteria for writing new directory structure back to the disk, but that also gives some other drawbacks, such as less reliable filesystem in case of crash/power loss).